# How to make drawImage position a variable inside canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

The problem is that the "position" variable is not beeing updated in order to make the digit display next to each other and not on top of each other.

I also tryed to put it inside the prototype function thinking that if it's beeing updated right before it runs the drawImage function it will work...but it does not and I do not understand what the problem is.

```
<pre>

var sprite = new Image();
     sprite.src = "Flappy_Bird_Sprite.png"

function drawSprite (img, x_crop, y_crop, x_width, y_height, x_pos, y_pos, x_posWidth, y_posHeight) {
    this.img = img;
    this.x_crop = x_crop;
    this.y_crop = y_crop;
    this.x_width = x_width;
    this.y_height = y_height;
    this.x_pos = x_pos;
    this.y_pos = y_pos;
    this.x_posWidth = x_posWidth;
    this.y_posHeight = y_posHeight;
}

   var position = 10;   
   drawSprite.prototype.draw = function () {

       ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x_crop, this.y_crop, this.x_width, this.y_height, this.x_pos, this.y_pos, this.x_posWidth, this.y_posHeight);
   }
                 var arr = [
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 137, 306, 7, 10, position, 50, 20, 40), 
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 139, 477, 5, 10, position, 50, 15, 40),
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 292, 160, 12, 18, position, 50, 15, 40),
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 306, 160, 12, 18, position, 50, 15, 40),
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 320, 160, 12, 18, position, 50, 15, 40),
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 334, 160, 12, 18, position, 50, 15, 40),
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 292, 184, 12, 18, position, 50, 15, 40),
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 306, 184, 12, 18, position, 50, 15, 40),
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 320, 184, 12, 18, position, 50, 15, 40),
                    new drawSprite(sprite, 334, 184, 12, 18, position, 50, 15, 40),
                    ]


     var increment = 0;

 function animate () {
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     increment++;

     if (increment % 10 == 0){
         score++;
     }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                var tString  = score.toString(); //Makeing the score into a string so I can select each number with the substring function
                var length = tString.length; //Finding out the length of the string(in our case is 2)

                for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){

                    var substring = tString.substring(i,i+1); //Selecting each digit of that number in order to draw each of them separately
                    var toNumber = parseInt(substring); //Setting that "string" back into a number so I can acces that number in the array

                     if( length == 2 ) { //I am trying to make this work for 2 digit number(10-99) and if this works, then I will add 3 digits and so on, I know that this should work only for numbers from 10-99

                            if( i == 0){ // Position the first digit of that number at the position ....
                                position = 180;
                            } 
                            if( i == 1){ // Position the second digit of that number at the position ....
                                position = 105;
                            } 

                    }        
                    arr[toNumber].draw();

            }     
 }

 animate();

<code>
```

Comment: Don't add your code on image. If anyone wants to reproduce your issue, she has to rewrite everything.

Comment: to add images related to design or screenshots to illustrate a problem. Not code. Unless it is something obvious, users here in stackoverflow will try to reproduce your issue by running the exact same code. If they cannot copy paste it easily, they will not bother.

Comment: Ok, thx for the answer

Comment: No. Problem. You are welcome. Hope you will solve your problem :)

Comment: Ok I got it, the only reason I inserted images is that I did not know how to format the code, but I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calls to `new drawSprite` all use the same value for `position`, which is fixed at the point you create those objects.

You could try updating the sprite instance before drawing:

```
arr[toNumber].x_pos = position;
arr[toNumber].draw();
```